# Silverstripe template, html-mode

Tags: emacs, silverstripe, html-mode

[Trying to get a mode to work with silverstipe templates](https://gist.github.com/1062600), but `<% end_control %>` breaks the indentation, but `<% nd_control %>` does not. It must be the `"<% end"`, but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

Comment: Could you perhaps make that two separate questions?

Comment: With "tabbing" do you mean indentation?

Comment: yes, I mean indentation. Sure, I'll make two question.

Comment: Here is the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583173/how-do-i-set-the-colour-of-a-custom-tag-in-html-mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this will be the part tripping it up end_[a-zA-Z1-9_.]*

I'm no lisp or regex expert. But I would suspect end_[:alpha:]+ should work. After taking a look at the emacs regex docs http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

You should be able to do without _ or . If you wanted to include the fullstop in the match I think you'll need double backslash \. But I can't think of an example when SS uses this in a closing template statement. And the underscore should already be matched with end_