# How do I set the colour of a custom tag in html-mode

Tags: templates, emacs, font-face, silverstripe, html-mode

[Trying to get a mode to work with silverstipe templates.](https://gist.github.com/1062600)

How do I set the background of the <% %> tag to be a darker color?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize any face using the customization system, but the trick is to know which face you have to edit to get the look that you want. There is a shortcut you can use in this case: position the point over the text in question and run M-x describe-face. This asks for a face name, but the default if you leave the input blank is the face used by the text at point. This gets you a help window with information about the face, including a link that takes you to its customization page.

Comment: Thank you, but I was trying to colour the background of the tag not change any of the already used faces. html-mode does nothing with <% %> tags (silverstripe template tag)

Comment: if it's leaving them in the default face then you'll need to change the mode itself to make it recognize them.

Comment: yes, that's why I linked to the mode I am trying to update to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your link, the face that highlights `<%` and `%>` is face `font-lock-keyword-face`.

If you want that face to be darker everywhere, then customize it, as @db48x suggested.

If you instead want to leave that face alone but have `<%` and `%>` be darker in `silverstripe-mode` then use a different, darker face in your `font-lock-add-keywords` expression.  Use `defface` to define a new face, and use that.